# Is there a way to collapse rows that belong to the same Table in Antd 2.x?

Tags: antd

I'm trying to make a row show more information that belong to the same table using antd and react (the data nested still belongs to the table, but it is collapsed) as is shown on image below. Searching on antd table documentation, I found a example to nest another table in the main table. Howerver, the second table also needs to have a Header besides it does not fallow the alignment of the first one. Could someone please explain me how I reach there?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsdib.png)
[antd table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsXBr.png)

Comment: Never mind guys, I found the children atribute that can be passed to a row and do exactly what I want.